# Прогрузка картинок на сайт при использовании библиотеки python eel

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

Делаю небольшую программу и хочу сделать сменяемый фон, который будет браться из директории программы bg и не важно, какое будет кол-во картинок, оно будет само подгружать их кол-во ( `len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])` ).
При запуске, запускается локальный хост localhost:(любой свободный порт). И он уже не может пройти по директории bg, как можно это обойти, или можно сделать какой нибудь прелоад картинок.

Пробовал так же и через python обращаться к функции из js с прогрузкой (`` document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<link rel="prefetch" href="bg/`+count+`.jpg">`); ``), но это уже слишком поздно

Comment: Ну, как бы легче это все брать через js и сделать setInterval для функии. Тогда через определенное кол-во секунд на странице будет меняться картинка. Как взять все картинки, думаю несложно в инете найти. Либо же через python передавать массив картинок и чтобы функция js проходилась по нему

Comment: Поменять фон это не проблема, у меня основная проблема, что сайт просто их не видит, и их просто поставить никак не получается, как я понял, уже при загрузке js он уже не имеет доступа к файлам

Comment: В смысле?-_- Вы просто поместите картинки в одну папку с index.html в папку img и оттуда берите картинки. Для простоты сделайте смену id через js, а в css для каждого id присвойте свой задний фон

Comment: Это то понятно, если запускать чисто как сайт, оно работает нормально, но при запуске через питон, он просто абстрагируется от директории из которой он запускается. **7.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** эта ошибка высвечивается в консоли, если использовать абсолютные ссылки или загружать на хостинги, то впринципе работает, но так пропадает весь смысл

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую быстренько написать и проверить

Comment: Сегодня/завтра отпишусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И такс, начну с структуры проекта:

```
main.py
site-----|img----|1.jpg
                 |2.jpg
         |index.html
         |style.css
         |script.js
```

### Теперь идут коды:

### main.py:

```
import eel
eel.init('site')
eel.start('index.html')
```

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Это моя программа</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p class='toogleParagraph' id='gg'>Вот туты должна меняться картинка</p>
    </div>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### style.css:

```
#gg{
    background-image: url(img/1.jpg);
    color: chocolate;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}
#bg{
    background-image: url(img/2.jpg);
    color: chartreuse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}
```

### script.js:

```
function toogleBackground(){
 let element = document.getElementsByClassName("toogleParagraph")[0];
    if(element.id == 'gg'){
        element.id = 'bg';
    }else{
        element.id = 'gg';
    };
};

setInterval(toogleBackground, 1000);
```

И так. Про `py`, `html` и `css` объяснять не буду, а вот `js` поясню.

Я сделал функцию, которая работает для смены картинок. Картинки все заданы `id` в `css` и делая смену `id` у элемента `p` я меняю цвет текста и фоновую картинку. Далее я всё запихнул в `setInterval`, чтобы картинка и цвет менялись каждую секунду.

Ну, и остаётся только [результат](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BjvhSDvvFeW5KHwvAG_ZsFwIotM1k9jR/view?usp=sharing)